# In Vulgate in Jacob 5:14, it says "Infirmatur quis *in vobis*?". How is that grammatical? Should not it use the partitive genitive "vestrum"?

Tags: new-testament, latin-vulgate

In Vulgate in Jacob 5:14, it says "Infirmatur quis *in vobis*?". How is that grammatical? Should not it use the partitive genitive "vestrum" instead of "in vobis"? Or at least "inter vos"? I mean, as far as I know, it is always translated as more-or-less "Is somebody suffering among you?". But "Infirmatur quis *in vobis*?" would mean "Is somebody suffering *inside you*?", right?

Comment: Perhaps this type of questions would receive better answers on [Latin.SE](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions) ?

Comment: @Lucian   Greek questions are commonly answered on SE-BH. I don't see why Latin should not be, also. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary Founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon*,<sup>1</sup>

[image]

In *Latin Grammar together with a Systematic Treatment of Latin Composition*,<sup>2</sup>

[image]

In *A Copious and Critical Latin-English Lexicon, Founded on the Larger Latin-German Lexicon of Dr. William Freund*,<sup>3</sup>

[image]

In *New Latin Grammar*,<sup>4</sup>

[image]

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> p. [911](https://books.google.com/books?id=IyAjAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA911#v=onepage&q&f=false), 1. *in*, I., A., 2.</sup>
        <sup><sup>2</sup> Part 2, p. [43](https://books.google.com/books?id=9SXgAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA43#v=onepage&q&f=false), Rem. 75</sup>
        <sup><sup>3</sup> p. [768](https://books.google.com/books?id=HNkEAQAAIAAJ&pg=RA52-PA15#v=onepage&q&f=false), 1. *in*, I., 2.</sup>
        <sup><sup>4</sup> §221, p. [133–134](https://books.google.com/books?id=fEEXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA133#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

In other words, the preposition *in* with a word declined in the ablative case (as *vobis* is) can function equivalent to a partitive genitive with the meaning of “among.”

---

**References**

Andrews, Erin Allen. [*A Copious and Critical Latin-English Lexicon, Founded on the Larger Latin-German Lexicon of Dr. William Freund.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=HNkEAQAAIAAJ) London: Ginn, 1876.

Allen, Joseph Henry; Greenough, James Bradstreet. [*New Latin Grammar.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fEEXAAAAYAAJ) Ed. Greenough, James Bradstreet; Howard, A. A.; D’ooge, Benjamin L.; Kittredge, G. L. Boston: Ginn, 1916.

Fischer, Gustavus. [*Latin Grammar together with a Systematic Treatment of Latin Composition.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=9SXgAAAAMAAJ) Part 2. New York: Schermerhorn, 1876.

Lewis, Charlton T.; Short, Charles. [*Harper’s Latin Dictionary: A New Latin Dictionary Founded on the Translation of Freund’s Latin-German Lexicon.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=IyAjAQAAMAAJ) New York: Harper & Brothers, 1891.

Comment: What about 'among (= gen. part.)' saying rather that 'among' can be equivalent to a partitive genitive? Is saying it in reverse really the same thing?